# CSS Cursor not working as expected

Tags: css, sass

I wann to make cursor to change grab mode when mouse over my div with class name `.grabber, CSS (it's sass)

```
.grabber{
   // not working
  cursor: grabb;
}
```

Comment: which browser did u check with?

Comment: There is no such thing. Try `cursor: -webkit-grab;` or `cursor: -moz-grab`

Comment: Latest Google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add with vendor prefixes, also you have made typo on your question its not `grabb` its `grab`.

```
.grabber{  
    cursor: grab;  
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
```